# Error in `python': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00005634ba7d3e80

Tags: python, tensorflow, malloc

When I call the `tf.Session()` the following error occurs. 
I have tried following ways,

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6968
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8717

But it doesn't work.

I've also tried reinstalling anaconda, using another virtual environment etc. Nothing works. Same error each time. In case I install, `libtcmalloc-minimal4` it doesn't show the backtrace. It only shows the `Aborted (core dumped)` message which is the last line of the following error.

```
*** Error in `python': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00005634ba7d3e80 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fe9c06097e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7fe9c061237a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fe9c061653c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1(+0x2edd7c)[0x7fe963908d7c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1(+0x2eddc3)[0x7fe963908dc3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1(+0x2ee064)[0x7fe963909064]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1(+0x1e0930)[0x7fe9637fb930]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1(+0x1baabc)[0x7fe9637d5abc]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1(cuInit+0x4e)[0x7fe96382456e]
/home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so(+0x9bd5a7)[0x7fe96d8945a7]
/home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so(_ZN9perftools8gputools4cuda10CUDADriver4InitEv+0x5d)[0x7fe96d89477d]
/home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so(_ZNK9perftools8gputools4cuda12CudaPlatform18VisibleDeviceCountEv+0x12)[0x7fe96d8a57e2]
/home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so(_ZN10tensorflow20BaseGPUDeviceFactory13CreateDevicesERKNS_14SessionOptionsERKSsPSt6vectorIPNS_6DeviceESaIS8_EE+0x85)[0x7fe96d795a85]
/home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so(_ZN10tensorflow13DeviceFactory10AddDevicesERKNS_14SessionOptionsERKSsPSt6vectorIPNS_6DeviceESaIS8_EE+0xed)[0x7fe96d7c726d]
/home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so(_ZN10tensorflow20DirectSessionFactory10NewSessionERKNS_14SessionOptionsE+0x98)[0x7fe97250e938]
/home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so(_ZN10tensorflow10NewSessionERKNS_14SessionOptionsEPPNS_7SessionE+0xff)[0x7fe96d80f1cf]
/home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so(TF_NewSession+0x25)[0x7fe96f99d485]
/home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so(+0x17b8271)[0x7fe96f5f9271]
python(_PyCFunction_FastCallDict+0x91)[0x5634b8748ad1]
python(+0x19e67c)[0x5634b87d867c]
python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x2fa)[0x5634b87facba]
python(+0x197a94)[0x5634b87d1a94]
python(+0x198941)[0x5634b87d2941]
python(+0x19e755)[0x5634b87d8755]
python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x10ba)[0x5634b87fba7a]
python(+0x197c26)[0x5634b87d1c26]
python(_PyFunction_FastCallDict+0x1bb)[0x5634b87d2e1b]
python(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x26f)[0x5634b8748f5f]
python(_PyObject_Call_Prepend+0x63)[0x5634b874da03]
python(PyObject_Call+0x3e)[0x5634b874899e]
python(+0x16b02b)[0x5634b87a502b]
python(+0x19e9b7)[0x5634b87d89b7]
python(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x8b)[0x5634b8748d7b]
python(+0x19e7ce)[0x5634b87d87ce]
python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x2fa)[0x5634b87facba]
python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x329)[0x5634b87d3459]
python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1c)[0x5634b87d41ec]
python(+0x2149a4)[0x5634b884e9a4]
python(+0xdb60c)[0x5634b871560c]
python(PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags+0xf3)[0x5634b87157c2]
python(+0xdb862)[0x5634b8715862]
python(+0xdda57)[0x5634b8717a57]
python(main+0xee)[0x5634b871a4be]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fe9c05b2830]
python(+0x1c7773)[0x5634b8801773]
======= Memory map: ========
5634b863a000-5634b88f9000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 4588166                    /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/bin/python3.6
5634b8af8000-5634b8afb000 r--p 002be000 08:02 4588166                    /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/bin/python3.6
5634b8afb000-5634b8b5e000 rw-p 002c1000 08:02 4588166                    /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/bin/python3.6
5634b8b5e000-5634b8b8f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
5634b9d28000-5634bbc10000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7fe8ee000000-7fe8f4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe8f4000000-7fe8f4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe8f4021000-7fe8f8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe8f8000000-7fe8f8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe8f8021000-7fe8fc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe8fc000000-7fe8fc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe8fc021000-7fe900000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe900000000-7fe900021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe900021000-7fe904000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe904000000-7fe904021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe904021000-7fe908000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe908000000-7fe908021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe908021000-7fe90c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe90c000000-7fe90c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe90c021000-7fe910000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe910000000-7fe910021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe910021000-7fe914000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe914000000-7fe914021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe914021000-7fe918000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe918000000-7fe918021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe918021000-7fe91c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe91c000000-7fe91c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe91c021000-7fe920000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe920000000-7fe920021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe920021000-7fe924000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe924000000-7fe924021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe924021000-7fe928000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe928ffa000-7fe928ffb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe928ffb000-7fe9297fb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9297fb000-7fe9297fc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9297fc000-7fe929ffc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe929ffc000-7fe929ffd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe929ffd000-7fe92a7fd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe92a7fd000-7fe92a7fe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe92a7fe000-7fe92affe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe92affe000-7fe92afff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe92afff000-7fe92b7ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe92b7ff000-7fe92b800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe92b800000-7fe92c000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe92c000000-7fe92c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe92c021000-7fe930000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe930000000-7fe930021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe930021000-7fe934000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe934000000-7fe934021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe934021000-7fe938000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe938000000-7fe938021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe938021000-7fe93c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe93c000000-7fe93c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe93c021000-7fe940000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe94031b000-7fe94031c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe94031c000-7fe940b1c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe940b1c000-7fe940b1d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe940b1d000-7fe94135d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe94135d000-7fe941568000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 28316252                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941568000-7fe941767000 ---p 0020b000 08:02 28316252                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941767000-7fe941777000 rw-p 0020a000 08:02 28316252                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941777000-7fe941778000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe941778000-7fe941779000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 270                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/_api_implementation.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941779000-7fe941978000 ---p 00001000 08:02 270                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/_api_implementation.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941978000-7fe941979000 rw-p 00000000 08:02 270                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/_api_implementation.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941979000-7fe941b79000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe941b79000-7fe941b7a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352239                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941b7a000-7fe941d7a000 ---p 00001000 08:02 18352239                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941d7a000-7fe941d7b000 r--p 00001000 08:02 18352239                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941d7b000-7fe941d7c000 rw-p 00002000 08:02 18352239                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941d7c000-7fe941d92000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352343                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941d92000-7fe941f92000 ---p 00016000 08:02 18352343                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941f92000-7fe941f93000 r--p 00016000 08:02 18352343                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941f93000-7fe941f98000 rw-p 00017000 08:02 18352343                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941f98000-7fe941fe7000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352354                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe941fe7000-7fe9421e7000 ---p 0004f000 08:02 18352354                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9421e7000-7fe9421ea000 r--p 0004f000 08:02 18352354                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9421ea000-7fe9421ec000 rw-p 00052000 08:02 18352354                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9421ec000-7fe9421f3000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352304                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/select.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9421f3000-7fe9423f2000 ---p 00007000 08:02 18352304                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/select.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9423f2000-7fe9423f3000 r--p 00006000 08:02 18352304                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/select.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9423f3000-7fe9423f5000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 18352304                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/select.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9423f5000-7fe9423f8000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352264                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9423f8000-7fe9425f7000 ---p 00003000 08:02 18352264                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9425f7000-7fe9425f8000 r--p 00002000 08:02 18352264                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9425f8000-7fe9425f9000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 18352264                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9425f9000-7fe9425ff000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352294                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/binascii.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9425ff000-7fe9427fe000 ---p 00006000 08:02 18352294                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/binascii.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9427fe000-7fe9427ff000 r--p 00005000 08:02 18352294                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/binascii.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9427ff000-7fe942800000 rw-p 00006000 08:02 18352294                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/binascii.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe942800000-7fe942a00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe942a27000-7fe942b67000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe942b67000-7fe942ba4000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 21244161                   /usr/lib/nvidia-390/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.390.30
7fe942ba4000-7fe942da3000 ---p 0003d000 08:02 21244161                   /usr/lib/nvidia-390/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.390.30
7fe942da3000-7fe942dae000 rw-p 0003c000 08:02 21244161                   /usr/lib/nvidia-390/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.390.30
7fe942dae000-7fe942db3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe942db3000-7fe94523c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 20725494                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.9.0.176
7fe94523c000-7fe94543b000 ---p 02489000 08:02 20725494                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.9.0.176
7fe94543b000-7fe94680d000 rw-p 02488000 08:02 20725494                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.9.0.176
7fe94680d000-7fe946d17000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe946d17000-7fe94eb45000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 20725487                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufft.so.9.0.176
7fe94eb45000-7fe94ed45000 ---p 07e2e000 08:02 20725487                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufft.so.9.0.176
7fe94ed45000-7fe94ed54000 rw-p 07e2e000 08:02 20725487                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcufft.so.9.0.176
7fe94ed54000-7fe94edb8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe94edb8000-7fe96336e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 19274550                   /usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.7.1.3
7fe96336e000-7fe96356e000 ---p 145b6000 08:02 19274550                   /usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.7.1.3
7fe96356e000-7fe9635c9000 rw-p 145b6000 08:02 19274550                   /usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.7.1.3
7fe9635c9000-7fe96361b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe96361b000-7fe963e5c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 19136851                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.390.30
7fe963e5c000-7fe96405c000 ---p 00841000 08:02 19136851                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.390.30
7fe96405c000-7fe9641ad000 rw-p 00841000 08:02 19136851                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.390.30
7fe9641ad000-7fe9641bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9641bb000-7fe9641cc000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18088702                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fe9641cc000-7fe9643cb000 ---p 00011000 08:02 18088702                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fe9643cb000-7fe9643cc000 r--p 00010000 08:02 18088702                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fe9643cc000-7fe9643cd000 rw-p 00011000 08:02 18088702                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fe9643cd000-7fe9644f7000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 21377824                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.24
7fe9644f7000-7fe9646f6000 ---p 0012a000 08:02 21377824                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.24
7fe9646f6000-7fe964700000 r--p 00129000 08:02 21377824                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.24
7fe964700000-7fe964704000 rw-p 00133000 08:02 21377824                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.24
7fe964704000-7fe964707000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe964707000-7fe964729000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18088714                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libgomp.so.1.0.0
7fe964729000-7fe964928000 ---p 00022000 08:02 18088714                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libgomp.so.1.0.0
7fe964928000-7fe964929000 r--p 00021000 08:02 18088714                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libgomp.so.1.0.0
7fe964929000-7fe96492a000 rw-p 00022000 08:02 18088714                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libgomp.so.1.0.0
7fe96492a000-7fe964993000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 20725445                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.9.0.176
7fe964993000-7fe964b92000 ---p 00069000 08:02 20725445                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.9.0.176
7fe964b92000-7fe964b96000 rw-p 00068000 08:02 20725445                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.9.0.176
7fe964b96000-7fe964b97000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe964b97000-7fe969546000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 20725472                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so.9.0.176
7fe969546000-7fe969746000 ---p 049af000 08:02 20725472                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so.9.0.176
7fe969746000-7fe969780000 rw-p 049af000 08:02 20725472                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so.9.0.176
7fe969780000-7fe969792000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe969792000-7fe96cc8c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 20725477                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.9.0.333
7fe96cc8c000-7fe96ce8c000 ---p 034fa000 08:02 20725477                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.9.0.333
7fe96ce8c000-7fe96cec7000 rw-p 034fa000 08:02 20725477                   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas.so.9.0.333
7fe96cec7000-7fe96ced7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe96ced7000-7fe96dbf2000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2022                       /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so
7fe96dbf2000-7fe96ddf1000 ---p 00d1b000 08:02 2022                       /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so
7fe96ddf1000-7fe96de36000 r--p 00d1a000 08:02 2022                       /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so
7fe96de36000-7fe96de37000 rw-p 00d5f000 08:02 2022                       /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so
7fe96de37000-7fe96de41000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe96de41000-7fe9928c6000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2028                       /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
7fe9928c6000-7fe992ac5000 ---p 24a85000 08:02 2028                       /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
7fe992ac5000-7fe992c2b000 r--p 24a84000 08:02 2028                       /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
7fe992c2b000-7fe992c39000 rw-p 24bea000 08:02 2028                       /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
7fe992c39000-7fe992d16000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe992d16000-7fe992ddb000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 675                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe992ddb000-7fe992fdb000 ---p 000c5000 08:02 675                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe992fdb000-7fe993000000 rw-p 000c5000 08:02 675                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993000000-7fe993042000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe993042000-7fe99304b000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 745                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack_lite.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe99304b000-7fe99324a000 ---p 00009000 08:02 745                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack_lite.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe99324a000-7fe99324b000 rw-p 00008000 08:02 745                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack_lite.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe99324b000-7fe99328b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe99328b000-7fe9932d0000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352353                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9932d0000-7fe9934cf000 ---p 00045000 08:02 18352353                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9934cf000-7fe9934d0000 r--p 00044000 08:02 18352353                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9934d0000-7fe9934d8000 rw-p 00045000 08:02 18352353                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9934d8000-7fe993518000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe993518000-7fe993541000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 768                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993541000-7fe993740000 ---p 00029000 08:02 768                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993740000-7fe993745000 rw-p 00028000 08:02 768                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993745000-7fe993749000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 769                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993749000-7fe993949000 ---p 00004000 08:02 769                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993949000-7fe99394c000 rw-p 00004000 08:02 769                        /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9939dd000-7fe993a1d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe993a1d000-7fe993a21000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352273                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993a21000-7fe993c20000 ---p 00004000 08:02 18352273                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993c20000-7fe993c21000 r--p 00003000 08:02 18352273                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993c21000-7fe993c22000 rw-p 00004000 08:02 18352273                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993c22000-7fe993c62000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe993c62000-7fe993c64000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352253                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993c64000-7fe993e63000 ---p 00002000 08:02 18352253                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993e63000-7fe993e64000 r--p 00001000 08:02 18352253                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993e64000-7fe993e65000 rw-p 00002000 08:02 18352253                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993e65000-7fe993e7b000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352339                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sha3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe993e7b000-7fe99407a000 ---p 00016000 08:02 18352339                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sha3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe99407a000-7fe99407b000 r--p 00015000 08:02 18352339                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sha3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe99407b000-7fe99407d000 rw-p 00016000 08:02 18352339                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sha3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe99407d000-7fe99408a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352322                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe99408a000-7fe994289000 ---p 0000d000 08:02 18352322                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe994289000-7fe99428a000 r--p 0000c000 08:02 18352322                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe99428a000-7fe99428b000 rw-p 0000d000 08:02 18352322                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe99428b000-7fe9944a1000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 4588141                    /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7fe9944a1000-7fe9946a0000 ---p 00216000 08:02 4588141                    /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7fe9946a0000-7fe9946bc000 r--p 00215000 08:02 4588141                    /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7fe9946bc000-7fe9946c7000 rw-p 00231000 08:02 4588141                    /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7fe9946c7000-7fe9946cb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9946cb000-7fe9946d1000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352295                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9946d1000-7fe9948d0000 ---p 00006000 08:02 18352295                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9948d0000-7fe9948d1000 r--p 00005000 08:02 18352295                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9948d1000-7fe9948d2000 rw-p 00006000 08:02 18352295                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9948d2000-7fe9948d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352265                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe9948d4000-7fe994ad4000 ---p 00002000 08:02 18352265                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe994ad4000-7fe994ad5000 r--p 00002000 08:02 18352265                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe994ad5000-7fe994ad6000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 18352265                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe994ad6000-7fe994afb000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 20187853                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/liblzma.so.5.2.3
7fe994afb000-7fe994cfa000 ---p 00025000 08:02 20187853                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/liblzma.so.5.2.3
7fe994cfa000-7fe994cfb000 r--p 00024000 08:02 20187853                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/liblzma.so.5.2.3
7fe994cfb000-7fe994cfc000 rw-p 00025000 08:02 20187853                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/liblzma.so.5.2.3
7fe994cfc000-7fe994d03000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 18352312                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe994d03000-7fe994f03000 ---p 00007000 08:02 18352312                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe994f03000-7fe994f04000 r--p 00007000 08:02 18352312                   /home/ntunlp/anaconda3/envs/sbmaruf/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.soAborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also encountered the same situation before:

Suggestion is try sudo apt-get install google-perftools

Reference could be found here:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6968

To understand this situation, you can refer to this post
[Understanding 'double free or corruption' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353712/understanding-double-free-or-corruption-error)